# ios - Sparrow mail app crashes on 5.0.1 - want to build a fix, mobile substrate help needed

Tags: objective-c, ios5, crash-reports, unrecognized-selector, cydia-substrate

yesterday, I downloaded the Sparrow mail app, which is crashing instant after startup.

Following crash log is generated:

```
Incident Identifier: [TODO]
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         Sparrow [64701]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2D0B2A21-4BE0-4A1E-9119-B16FAA3A1572/Sparrow.app/Sparrow
Identifier:      com.sparrowmailapp.iphoneapp
Version:         507.54
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-14 23:57:46 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A406)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x305e132c
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UINavigationBar setShadowImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b1e70'
```

The problem is the property "shadowImage" in UINavigationBar, which doesn't exist on iOS 5.

Now i´m trying to build a mobile substrate addon to avoid the crash, adding the missing property to UINavigationBar with overwrite and following code:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UINavigationBar(MyNavigationBar)
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *shadowImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end

%hook UINavigationBar

- (void)setShadowImage:(UIImage *)shadowImage forToolbarPosition:(id)topOrBottom {
    %log;
    //%orig;
}


- (void)setShadowImage:(UIImage *)shadowImage {
    %log;
    //%orig;
}

%end;
```

I have no idea, to set the shadowImage or UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god, these methods should be normal setter/getter of the shadowImage.

Problem resolved.